# Azure function CSOM The remote server returned an error:(400) bad request

Tags: csom, http-400-bad-request, azure-functions

I am trying to make a simple query to sharepoint online using Azure function created in VS2017.

My code looks like below:

```
List mylist = myweb.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='RequestedForDeletion' /><Value Type='Boolean'>False</Value></Neq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='LinkTitle' /><FieldRef Name='SiteUrl_x0028_alias_x0029_' /><FieldRef Name='RequestedForDeletion' /><FieldRef Name='CurrentStatus' /></ViewFields><QueryOptions /></View>";
ListItemCollection items = mylist.GetItems(camlQuery);
myclientContext.Load(items);
myclientContext.ExecuteQuery();
log.Info($"Empty items: {items.Count}");
```

It is the myclientContext.ExecuteQuery(); where I get error as :
"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"

I am unable to understand the reason for this error.
Any help or explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting this error is because [`CamlQuery.ViewXml` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.viewxml.aspx) expects a *valid* CAML query enclosed within `View` element.

Here are a few examples on how to construct a CAML query:

For *empty* query

```
 var camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
 camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View/>";
```

For *predefined* query

```
var camlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
```

For *user-defined* query:

```
var camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope =\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
```

Rererences

[How to: Retrieve List Items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee534956(v%3Doffice.14))